# Can type to value meta-function be used as variable alias in C++14?

Tags: c++, type-traits, c++14, template-aliases, variable-templates

While looking at C++14 the meta-function alias proposals ([TransformationTraits Redux, v2,N3655](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3655.pdf)), I noticed that, not only type to type transformations (such as `add_const`), type to value meta-functions (such as `is_void` ) are also type aliased. (Which are not present in [N3797](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf)).

Is there any advantage of aliasing type to value meta-functions? I think, it is possible to use them without those aliases, such as `enable_if_t<is_void<T>::value,T>` or `enable_if_t<is_void<T>{}(),T>` when the conversion operation is present. (I guess `is_void<T>::type::value` is same as `is_void<T>::value`)

If the type to value meta-functions need to be aliases, wont it be better to alias them as variable template ( I do not have C++14 compiler and never used variable template. So the syntax may be wrong)?  e.g. alias `is_void` as

```
template <class T>
constexpr bool is_void_t = is_void<T>::value;
```

Instead of

```
template <class T>
using is_void_t = typename is_void<T>::type;
```

Then one can write `enable_if_t<is_void_t<T>,T>` without boost style `enable_if`,and composing expression will be easier (e.g. `enable_if_t<(is_void_t<T> || is_integral_t<T>),T>`

Comment: "I do not have C++14 compiler" - http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/

Comment: @chris Do gcc 4.8 has variable template support? It looks gcc svn trunk has some support for it. clang also seems to have support for it in their trunk. Do you know any online compiler having latest c++14 snapshot to test?

Comment: Coliru uses the SVN version of Clang.

Comment: I just tested it, but it seems Clang 3.4 (trunk 184460) from Coliru does not have support for variable template.

Comment: That's odd, especially considering other features marked SVN (like return type deduction) do work.

Comment: @chris 184460 is "rather old", the current SVN trunk is 195971 AFAIK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*“Is there any advantage of aliasing type to value meta-functions?”*

Quoting from the linked N3655, before the specifications of `is_void_t` and siblings (page 4):

> #### 4   Supplementary proposed wording
>
> The following wording is provided in response to LWG’s request that aliases for **`::type`** members be consistently provided for all the type traits, not only for those classified as *TransformationTraits*. Accordingly, this section provides the specifications needed in order to complete the set.

That explains why *“type to value meta-functions (such as `is_void` ) are also type aliased”* in the proposal: for consistency.

Moreover, it would be wrong to use the name “`is_void_t`” to alias `is_void<T>::value`. The “`_t`” suffix always denotes a **type**. For the value, maybe one could use a “**`_v`**” suffix. So we would then have both:

```
template <class T>
using is_void_t = typename is_void<T>::type;

template <class T>
constexpr bool is_void_v = is_void<T>::value;
```

That should compile in C++14, and then you could write things like `enable_if_t<(is_void_v<T> || is_integral_v<T>),T>`. But I feel that the value alias is “less needed” than the type one: it doesn't save as much typing, and, as you said, you can use the short `is_void<T>{}()` with the same effect (and for C++11, `is_void<T>{}` is often enough, thanks to its `operator bool()`).

Comment: *"and for C++11, `is_void<T>{}` is often enough, thanks to its `operator bool()`"* I'd even say it's *always enough*, as those traits (*Unary* and *BinaryTypeTraits*, [meta.rqmts]) derive from `std::integral_constant`, which provides this conversion operator.

Comment: @DyP Strictly speaking, `is_void<T>{}()` is a `bool`, but `is_void<T>{}` is only _implicitly convertible_ to a `bool`, which might (rarely) be an “important” difference, e.g. with overload resolution or any situation where you care about the exact types. By the way, maybe that's why they added `operator()()` for C++14? (edit: found [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3545.pdf))

Comment: @gx_ While looking through C++ Draft (N3797) I had not found any reference to is_void_t etc, but only to the transform traits. Does that mean, the other aliases are not accepted? is_void_v is OK, but i had no idea _t denotes type transformation!

Comment: @abir According to the Editor's Report [N3692](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3692.html): _“Section 4 of the proposal was not applied, as per the LWG motion.”_ And from [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.c%2B%2B.isocpp.proposals/3841): _“The project editor had severe concerns in regard to this extended
addition requiring about 4 additional pages in the standard with
questionable value, therefore it was withdrawn at this point of time.
This doesn't mean that it could not be added in the future.”_ It seems that it still hasn't been added, indeed.

Comment: @gx_ You're right; the two reasons listed in n3545 are *to create function objects* and *to allow usage in context w/o implicit conversion, and w/o using a `static_cast`*. Though frankly I don't understand what they mean with *"The standard library’s `enable_if` and `conditional` type traits exemplify contexts that do not
engender such implicit conversion."* -- AFAIK, `std::enable_if<std::true_type{}>` is well-formed.

Comment: The `some_trait_v` notation has actually been proposed by Stephan T. Lavavej in [N3854](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3854.htm) and [N3932](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3932.htm)